# Use #inst in an .edn file to seed a timestamp to jdbc database in clojure

Tags: clojure, edn

I'm using an `.edn` file as a database seed and need a way to set a timestamp in that file and have it written to the db without a java error. (It turns out you can't just enter a timestamp as a string and have it convert automatically as some of us may be used to in more dynamic languages than java).

I've got as far as the following `.edn` file which seeds correctly if I remove the `#inst` and just put nil instead.

```
[{:table :subscriptions
  :data [{:user_id 1
          :price 9900
          :transacted_at nil
          :begin_at nil
          :end_at #inst "2020-01-01T22:00:01-07:00"}]}]
```

But with the `#inst` included as above gives this error:

```sh
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException:
Can't infer the SQL type to use for an instance of java.util.Date. 
Use setObject() with an explicit Types value
```

The question here is how to fix that specific error and get a timestamp into the database.

Answer (score 5):

The EDN file is fine. Your problem comes from the JDBC driver when you attempt to insert the data. You don't say which Clojure JDBC library you are using, but if you are using `next.jdbc`, you should require the `next.jdbc.date-time` namespace and that will automatically enable conversion from `java.util.Date` to a valid PostgreSQL data type.

Comment: thanks. i hadn't realised there was a choice of jdbc drivers. i'm using clojure.java.jdbc. should i change to next.jdbc?

Comment: @sean_corfield  When you say "valid postgresql datatype", i'm confused because sql is based on text and is not typed (although certainly postgresql has types after it has interpreted the sql text.). Do you mean valid datatype for the java postgresql driver?

Comment: @sean_corfield I can see that you are the author of next.jdbc. I'll definitely consider using that in future but right now I need the simplest solution that works, simply to get started. I wonder if there is a way to do this with clojure.java.jdbc or whether that would be more difficult. Most of the good books on clojure I have teach that library and my feeling is I should possibly know how to use that one first in order to then appreciate jdbc.next.

Comment: 1. clojure.java.jdbc and next.jdbc are not JDBC drivers, they are Clojure libraries. You need a JDBC driver as well -- which is database-specific (and vendor-specific: there can be multiple drivers for a given database).

Comment: 2. SQL does indeed have types. And they are not the same as Java (or Clojure) types. TIMESTAMP is a SQL type. In Java/Clojure you would use java.util.Date, java.sql.Timestamp, java.time.Instant etc.

Comment: 3. To make this work with clojure.java.jdbc, you will need to extend ISQLParameter to java.util.Date so that set-parameter will call .setTimestamp (so, similar code to how next.jdbc.date-time does it, but a different protocol needs extending). I'm the maintainer of both libraries, by the way.

Comment: Meta comment regarding clojure.java.jdbc and next.jdbc: c.j.j will probably not get any more releases (it's at 0.7.11 now) as all future work is focused on next.jdbc, which is essentially the 1.0.x version of c.j.j. Yes, it has a slightly different API. Yes, most of the existing books/tutorials use c.j.j. No, you don't need to know c.j.j to use next.jdbc (the docs for c.j.j are much thinner and will not be updated).